# Can’t mount external drive - Mojave

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, mojave

[image]came up here after a lot of looking around. Even seen a couple of examples of my issue,  JT not sure what to do. Have tried a bunch of stuff and still cannot not get drive to mount. Apple says to wait for a call back in a week after the holidays. Doubt that anyone is reading here now, but.....  tying anyway. Older HP external drive and recently upgraded to Mojave. Here is some of the details I posted on Apple ———-

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2

Not on the actual computer now but for the life of me can’t figure it out. Any ideas - all my back files are there. Tks Stumped.

Edit add info:

High Sierra previous os. run in safe mode, empty caches, remove .plist for time machine, try on another Mac, run iboysoft recovery software. cannot unmount as it won't mount. HP5000s drive. Drive just spins and spins showing activity but won't mount. connected by usb to MBP w/ Mojave. Tks! – Stumped 6 mins ago

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  What were the error messages?  "Tried a bunch of stuff" is not a good description of things you did.  "Older HP external drive"  - what does that mean?  USB?  Firewire?  Did it work before on your previous OS?  What was that previous OS?

Comment: High Sierra previous os.  run in safe mode, empty caches, remove .plist for time machine, try on another Mac, run iboysoft recovery software.  cannot unmount as it won't mount.  HP5000s drive.  Drive just spins and spins showing activity but won't mount.  connected by usb to MBP w/ Mojave.  Tks!

Comment: Please be sure to  [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/346536/edit) you question with the relevant details.

Comment: Was it working in the previous OS?  Did it work on a different Mac?  Please, be specific - remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder.

Comment: Sorry.  Yes and yes. Thought I put that in your 1st request. Was working with high Sierra and it did work on a different Mac a few years back b4 it was moved to the present MBP. Tks

Answer (score 1):

From Terminal, what happens if you try:

```
sudo diskutil repairVolume disk2s2
sudo diskutil mount disk2s2
```

This will run the Disk Utility disk repair process. Can you report back with any errors or output you get.

You can also try booting into Single User Mode (at start-up hold down Command-S). That'll drop you into a command-prompt and you can try

```
sudo fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk2s2
shutdown -r now
```

That runs a filesystem check (hence fsck), and can also repair damage, then reboots. After the reboot, check and see if it mounts.

Comment: Alex - guessing you want me to do your suggestions while the external drive is attached and spinning??

Comment: Hey Alex - I couldn’t do the 1st 2 diskutil commands - system kept asking for a password even though I’m logged in as admin. user. For each of the commands I was asked for a password 3 times then got the command prompt. This computer has no password protection. But I am in the process of doing sudo fsck command in your 2nd set of commands and here is where we’re at.....  FYI.

Comment: Yes, while attached and spinning. Your account needs to be an admin on the box, and then it takes your regular password. If there's no password set, I'm not sure if it needs you to hit enter, or just won't work till you set a password.

Comment: Can’t figure out how to post a current pic of what it’s doing. Looks like it’s starting over with the fsck

Comment: finally had to shut it down.  just keep running in a loop.

Comment: There's no loop in that image. How long did you let it run for?

Comment: sorry for the delay.  about 2 hours....  also, found out that i have to add a password to computer to run from terminal.  added password and ran sudo pkill -f fsck from terminal and it killed the disk.  i was then able to see the drive mounted.  i then ran from disk utility, disk repair and it ran for about 3 hours and i got the above - not able to repair.  sorry for the cut and paste, i could not figure out how to copy the lines from inside disk util window.  does this help?  still won't repair or mount unless i run this line again sudo pkill -f fsck.....

Comment: At this point I'd worry about the drive. If you space elsewhere, just copy the data off it, reformat it, and copy the databack. Not sure if you can do that with TimeMachine back-ups, but last I checked they're just disk images under the covers. There's also a likelihood that it's a failing drive and needs replacing. If you can mount it, get a replacement disk and use something like Carbon Copy Cloner to dupe the old to new drive.

Comment: Got it. Tks!  Got a new 4 TB for Xmas. The old one is real old so gonna try and copy and see how it goes. Tks for all the suggestions.

Comment: So I tried to drag and drop main back up file from old drive to new 4tb drive. Ran for about 11 hours. Last 4 hours window said 5 seconds left and 0 files left to copy. But the size of the copy amount kept climbing. I stopped it finally after got to almost 600 gig even though source drive was only 500 gig.  I then tried using disk utility and got some error message that old drive could not be used as source.....  Stumpted again